# SQLITE3 SELECT statement returns no data

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have a 2-table DB in SQLite3, using the sqlite3 package in python. there is a 'sensor' table that describes sensors (currently a bit over 1000 sensors) and a sensordata table that contains time-stamped data from the sensors. I am trying to get sensordata for a short list of sensors within a date range. When I run the query in SQLiteStudio, I get about 1200 rows, but running in python I get None for a result. I copy the exact SELECT statement from python in SQLiteStudio to compare.

Here is the python code for a method that should return results from the select statement:

```
def selectSensorDataByPAID_Dates(self,ids,dateStrs=None):
  """Selects from the sensordata table using list of ids
  and a 2-item list of dates (start,end)
  Default for dates is full date range 
  """
  rtrn=None
  if dateStrs==None:
    dateStrs=['2000-06-16 08:34:06',str(datetime.datetime.now())]
  if len(ids)<1:
    return rtrn
  idslst=",".join(map(str,ids))
  slctStmnt="""SELECT sensordata.id as sdid, sensordata.datetime,
    sensordata.PM2_5Value,
    sensordata.temp_C,
    sensordata.humidity,
    sensordata.barom,
    sensors.PA_id,sensors.id as snsrid,sensors.label
    FROM sensordata
    INNER JOIN sensors ON sensordata.sensors_id=sensors.id
    WHERE (sensors.PA_id in ({}))
    and sensordata.datetime > '{}'
    and sensordata.datetime < '{}'
    ORDER BY sensordata.datetime ASC, sensors.PA_id;
    """.format(idslst,dateStrs[0],dateStrs[1])
  try:
    self.__crsr.execute(slctStmnt).fetchone()
  except DatabaseError as err:
    print(err)
  except Error as err:
    print(err)
  return rtrn
```

Here is the resulting SELECT statement that runs fine in SQLiteStudio:

```
SELECT sensordata.id as sdid, sensordata.datetime,
  sensordata.PM2_5Value,
  sensordata.temp_C,
  sensordata.humidity,
  sensordata.barom,
  sensors.PA_id,sensors.id as snsrid,sensors.label
  FROM sensordata
  INNER JOIN sensors ON sensordata.sensors_id=sensors.id
  WHERE (sensors.PA_id in (8942,24347))
  and sensordata.datetime > '2000-06-16 08:34:06'
  and sensordata.datetime < '2019-06-07 07:16:21.101885'
  ORDER BY sensordata.datetime ASC, sensors.PA_id;
```

Why do I get different results from Python vs SQLiteStudio??

Comment: My very first suggestion is to print out the SQL query which your Python script is generating.

Comment: Not sure if this is your answer, so I am only commenting but you should assign the result of `fetchone` to something. `self.__crsr.execute(slctStmnt).fetchone()`

Comment: @Lafexios: I'M and IDIOT!!! I did not assign the result of fethcall(0 to rtrn!!! Doing that fixed all.....